# Helping with a layout xml issue

Tags: android-layout

I want to put the checkmark inside the Name text as in the image, but I couldn't, no matter what I do, it stays outside and when the Name gets longer, the checkmark disappears. What I want to do is to have the Checkmark next to the Name text and give a match_parent

My code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:text="Hiddy"
    android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/verified"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_verify"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:text="hiddy"
    android:textColor="?attr/texttwocolor"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm5x1.png)